# django model forms does'nt save the data

Tags: django, forms, model, save

i want to create a todolist app with django.
i created a form for list model but when the user click on submit to submit a list, the form is'nt saved, why?

this is views.py
i have created an instance of the form and set the user field to it and then save the instance but fact it does'nt

```
def index(request):
    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user_ = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
        lists = user_.user.all()
        form = listForm()
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = listForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                instance = form.save(commit=False)
                instance.user = request.user
                instance.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
        context = {'lists':lists, 'form':form}   
        return render(request, 'todolists/index.html', context)
    else:
        return render(request, 'todolists/login.html')
```

this is index template

```
{% extends "todolists/layout.html" %}
{% block body %}
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
    <div class="center-column">
        <form method="POST" action="{% url 'index' %}"> 
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{form.title}}
            <input type="submit" class="btn btn-info">
        </form>
        <div class="todo-list">
            {% for list in lists %}
                <div class="item-row">
                    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-info" href="{% url 'update' list.id %}">update</a>
                    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" href="{% url 'update' list.id %}">delete</a>
                    <span>{{list}}</span>
                </div>
            {% endfor %}
        </div>
    </div>
{% endif %} 
{% endblock %}
```

this is urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .import views

urlpatterns = [
   path('', views.index, name='index'),
   path('update/<str:id>/', views.update, name='update'),
   path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
   path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
   path("register", views.register, name="register"),
]
```

this is models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser

# Create your models here.
class User(AbstractUser):
    pass

    
class list(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    finished = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    timestamps = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="user")
        
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

here is the form code

```
class listForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title= forms.CharField(label=mark_safe("<span style='color:white;'>Title:</span>"),
     widget= forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Add new task...', 'class':'form-control'}))
    finished= forms.BooleanField(label=mark_safe("<span style='color:white;'>Finished:</span>"),
     widget= forms.CheckboxInput(attrs={'style':'width:25px;'}))

    class Meta:
        model = list
        fields = '__all__'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try updating your template file `{{ form.title }}` to `{{ form }}` as mentioned in django docs here is the [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/forms/#the-template)

Update your forms.py file if want only `title` field in the HTML

```
class listForm(forms.ModelForm):
    title= forms.CharField(label=mark_safe("<span style='color:white;'>Title:</span>"),
     widget= forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder':'Add new task...', 'class':'form-control'}))
    

    class Meta:
        model = list
        fields = ('title', )
```

Comment: thanks for answering the question, it worked but i want the title field only is shown in the template, how can i do that?

Comment: i have added it

Comment: Updated my answer. Happy Coding :)